# Custom ActiveRecord Model Generator to Change File Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm currently trying to figure out how to extend the default ActiveRecord generator to use a different file path other than app/models and db/migrate. I've found the sources for the generators [for models](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator.rb) and [for migrations](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb), but I'm unsure how to extend or override them to create my own generators that can use almost all of the ActiveRecord ones' functionality.

Ideally, the generators would act exactly the same as the current ActiveRecord generators, with only the generated file path changed. And it would be nice if I didn't end up duplicating the code from the ActiveRecord source. Has anyone created a custom generator like this? Are there any examples I could look at? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you anticipated this response, but this seems like a very bad idea indeed! Secretly overwriting basic Rails functionality can cause all sorts of problems if someone else comes along and the standard Rails stuff doesn't work as they expected. If it's important that you are able to use this generator then you could write a new rake task, separate from the Rails one.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't mean to override the default, but more to create a new generator that did the exact same thing as the current ones. The problem is, I can't figure out how to change just the generated file path using my own generator. I also don't want to copy and paste the source for the ActiveRecord generators if all I'm doing is changing where the files are placed. I've edited my question to better reflect what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!